# Reading content from REST web service in MATLAB

Tags: json, matlab, rest, web-services

I'm using the webread() function to retrieve sunrise and sunset data from the sunrise-sunset.org api [here](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api).

here is what my code looks like:

```
function [E_total] = solar_energy(lng, lat, yr, month, day)

% Generate URL
url = strcat('https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=', num2str(lat),...
       '&lng=', num2str(lng), '&date=', num2str(yr), '-', num2str(month),... 
       '-',num2str(day));

% Retrieve data
forecast = webread(url)

if isempty(forecast)  % Failed, use default estimates
    sunrise = 6;
    sunset = 18;
    noon = 12;
elseif forecast.status == 'OK'
    % Success!  Parse retrieved data...
    forecast.results
    dv = datevec(forecast.results.sunrise)
    sunrise = dv(6)/3600 + dv(5)/60 + dv(4)
    dv = datevec(forecast.results.sunset)
    sunset = dv(6)/3600 + dv(5)/60 + dv(4)
    dv = datevec(forecast.results.solar_noon)
    noon = dv(6)/3600 + dv(5)/60 + dv(4)
end
```

here is an example of what I get for sunrise and sunset data for 12/2/2017 at the washington national monument.

Input:

> solar_energy( -77.0353, 38.8895, 2017, 12, 02)

Here is what I get:

> forecast =
>
> ```
> results: [1x1 struct]
>  status: 'OK'
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>                     sunrise: '12:00:01 AM'
>                      sunset: '12:00:01 AM'
>                  solar_noon: '9:38:38 AM'
>                  day_length: '00:00:00'
>        civil_twilight_begin: '12:00:01 AM'
>          civil_twilight_end: '12:00:01 AM'
>     nautical_twilight_begin: '12:00:01 AM'
>       nautical_twilight_end: '12:00:01 AM'
> astronomical_twilight_begin: '12:00:01 AM'
>   astronomical_twilight_end: '12:00:01 AM'
> ```

Is there something wrong in my method or is there an issue with this api?
The data is retrieved successfully, but for all the dates the sunrise and sunset times either read 12:00:00 AM or they are at 9 something AM.

Comment: Well... if data returned from the API call is wrong, changes are the API is failing. I tried running your code and I'm getting the same problem, but with "PM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found your problem. I gave a look at the [API documentation](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api) and I discovered it supports an additional parameter called `formatted`, which is described as follows:

> **formatted** (integer): 0 or 1 (1 is default). Time values in response
>   will be expressed following ISO 8601 and day_length will be expressed
>   in seconds. Optional.

I tried appending it to the request created in your function. In the meanwhile, I also fixed a small problem concerning the `date parameter` you were using in your call:

> **date** (string): Date in YYYY-MM-DD format. Also accepts other date
>   formats and even relative date formats. If not present, date defaults
>   to current date. Optional.

The 'DD' format for days express the day value in two digits (for example: `21` if day value is `21`, `02` if day value is `2`). Using `num2str` doesn't reproduce this behavior since `num2str(2) = '2'` and `num2str(02) = '2'`. A quick fix is using `datestr(day,'dd')` instead.

Here is the final result:

```
solar_energy(-77.0353, 38.8895, 2017, 12, 02);

function [E_total] = solar_energy(lng, lat, yr, month, day)

    url = strcat('https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json', ...
        '?lat=', num2str(lat), ...
        '&lng=', num2str(lng), ...
        '&date=', num2str(yr),'-',num2str(month),'-',datestr(day,'dd'), ...
        '&formatted=0');

    forecast = webread(url);

    if (isempty(forecast) || ~strcmp(forecast.status,'OK'))
        sunrise = 6;
        noon = 12;
        sunset = 18;
    else
        forecast.results
    end

end
```

This is the result that the code above produces:

> ```
>                     sunrise: '2017-12-02T12:09:28+00:00'
>                      sunset: '2017-12-02T21:46:20+00:00'
>                  solar_noon: '2017-12-02T16:57:54+00:00'
>                  day_length: 34612
>        civil_twilight_begin: '2017-12-02T11:40:03+00:00'
>          civil_twilight_end: '2017-12-02T22:15:44+00:00'
>     nautical_twilight_begin: '2017-12-02T11:06:58+00:00'
>       nautical_twilight_end: '2017-12-02T22:48:50+00:00'
> astronomical_twilight_begin: '2017-12-02T10:34:47+00:00'
>   astronomical_twilight_end: '2017-12-02T23:21:01+00:00'
> ```

As you can see, the values returned look correct. So the problem is caused by how the `API` handles the conversion of the dates it retrieves from the database in `ISO 8601` to another format.

Of course, you have to change the way you are currently parsing the values returned by the `API`. This should do the job:

```
datevec(struct.sunrise,'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss');
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you sir!!